# XPath advanced search based on other attribute of the XML

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to build and XPath query to select an element according to the attribute of another element. My XML goes like this:

```
<datadoc>
     <data>
    <molecule coorddimension="3">
      <properties>
        <property name="Mol2_MolInfo_Name" type="stringvalue">
          <val>ZINC01532215_1</val>
        </property>        
      </properties>
      <atom key="0" element="6" x="8.2965" y="42.3268" z="14.1097">
        <properties>
          <property name="AtomName" type="stringvalue">
            <val>C1</val>
          </property>         
        </properties>
      </atom>       
      <atom key="9" element="6" x="7.3131" y="43.2537" z="13.9462">
        <properties>
          <property name="AtomName" type="stringvalue">
            <val>C10</val>
          </property>        
        </properties>
      </atom>               
      <bond atomref1="0" atomref2="9" type="double">
        <properties>
          <property name="BondSybylType" type="stringvalue">
            <val>ar</val>
          </property>
        </properties>
      </bond>
     </molecule>
    </data>
  </datadoc>
```

Basically what I want is to select the Atom which @key attribute is referenced by a Bond in @atomref1 y @atomref2 bond's attributes. That's it, being in a Bond node, get the Atom element referenced by that Bond.

What I tried is something like this:

```
../atom[@key = ./@atomref1]
```

I use .. because when I do the query I am in Bond node, but that does not seem to work. Any ideas if that can be done with XPath?

Thanks.

Comment: If you can, post your Java code or an excerpt of it. Also, post a "more complex" XML extract, with multiple `bond`

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
.//atom[@key=../bond/@atomref1]
```

If you want to match @atomref2:

```
.//atom[@key=../bond/@atomref2]
```

If you want both `<atom>`:

```
.//atom[@key=../bond/@atomref1 or @key=../bond/@atomref2]
```

Comment: Could you refer a good `xpath2.0` and `xpath1.0` supported test tool(offline) ?

Comment: No no.. I am asking for myself,as what I have in my ubuntu laptop,is not supporting many of the xpath expressions,thus I am looking for a advanced one..

Comment: I use almost exclusively `lxml` (and its `lxml.etree.xpath()`) in Python shell to verify XPath 1.0 expression. `lxml` does not support XPath 2.0

Comment: The problem with this solution is in the case that we have more atom and bond elements. The above XPath query will get all the atoms referenced by any Bond, and not just the atoms referenced but the Bond in which I am.

Comment: If you have a condition on `<bond>`, you can add it inside, e.g. `.//atom[@key=../bond[.//property[@name="BondSybylType"]/val="ar"]/@atomref1]`. Do you have a longer sample with more `<bond>` and example targets you want to select?

Comment: When you say "[you are] in a Bond", what language/toolkit are you using?

Comment: Can there be multiple `bond` per `molecule`?

Comment: Yes, they are multiple bond per molecule. I am programing from Java

Comment: If you are looping on `bond`, you could keep the index of the bond and select atoms like this: `../atom[@key = ../bond[i]/@atomref1]` where `i` is the current bond position relative to the `molecule` (remember XPath positions start at 1). You probably should post your Java code as well, since it may not be possible to solve with XPath only.

Comment: First, I select the Bond `/molecule/bond` and for each bond I want to get its own information, like the atoms it references

Comment: Ok, just saw your other comment. Yes, I was looking for a solution using just XPath, but it seems that it is not possible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If all bonds look the same, back-referencing it through its position (see my comment above) may work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this in pure xpath (finding the atoms that participate in *this specific* bond), because you don't have access to the outer context when you are inside the predicate on `atom`. If you were in XSLT you could use the `current()` function which provides a reference to the outer context:

```
../atom[@key = (current()/@atomref1| current()/@atomref2)]
```

but this is an XSLT specific function, not available in standard XPath.

Depending how you are executing your XPath expression you may be able to provide variable bindings. Since you state in a comment that you're working in Java, here is an example using javax.xml.xpath:

```
class MapVariableResolver extends HashMap<String, Object> implements XPathVariableResolver {
  public Object resolveVariable(QName name) {
    return get(name.getLocalPart());
  }
}

XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
MapVariableResolver mvr = new MapVariableResolver();
xp.setXPathVariableResolver(mvr);

Node bond = // ... however you get the bond element
mvr.put("current", bond);
NodeList atoms = (NodeList)xp.evaluate(
    "../atom[@key = ($current/@atomref1| $current/@atomref2)]",
    bond,
    XPathConstants.NODESET);
```